# Why Nuxt client side navigate not request new doc?

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, server-side-rendering

When I first access nuxt server, the chrome doc of network tool show the request. but when click to navigate to a detail page, this haven't doc request. What is the reason.
[image]

[image]

I'm not found related explain of nuxt ssr. I hope you can answer my confusion.

it's really preload next page js. but when we view web page source code on detail page. We can also see corresponding raw html. why vue-router can achieve this effect. How to achieve rendering of Vue components into HTML content. This is my confusion.

Comment: Remove the `doc` filter, you may have some JS coming in. Otherwise it's maybe already preloaded/available. More info overall is welcome about your configuration.

Comment: it's really preload next page js. but when we view web page source code on detail page. We can also see corresponding raw html. why vue-router can achieve this effect. How to achieve rendering of Vue components into HTML content. This is my confusion.

Comment: Not sure to fully understand. Are you using SSR/SSG or SPA-only? What is your end goal also? SEO?

Comment: I use ssr mode. i want to know when navigate to detail page to view web page source code by chrome, i can see corresponding raw html doc. How did this happen. Actually, this does not request html document from the server . How does client rendering achieve complete HTML file content after navigation. SPA application can't implement seo but it can do. Looking forward to your answer @kissu

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood it. In fact, the browser's view of the source code of the webpage re-requested this address from the server. So the client routing did not actually generate the raw html.